# Merging two mysql requests (SELECT and UPDATE) into one

Tags: php, mysql

I have two mysql tables:

- a table called `rawmats` which stores the quantity of some raw materials;
- another one called `stock_changes` storing events, when the stock of a certain material is changing (the delta quantity is stored, bound with the material id).

I need to make a mysql request in order to undo all the changes stored in the `stock_changes` table, to the actual stock stored in `rawmats`.

Presently, the following php code is doing it well:

```
$stock_changes_req = $db->prepare('SELECT rawmat_id, delta FROM stock_changes');
$stock_update_req = $db->prepare('UPDATE rawmats SET stock = stock - :delta WHERE id=:rawmat_id');

$stock_changes_req->execute();
$stock_changes = $stock_changes_req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($stock_changes as $stock_change)
    $stock_update_req->execute($stock_change);
```

There are two questions about it:

- Is it possible to merge these two requests (and the php loop) into one big mysql request? I guess it could be better if it was coded this way
- If a merge is possible, would it be beneficial in terms of performance? I personnally think so, because it would replace two mysql requests and a php loop, to only one big mysql request. If the performance gain is only small, then my question would have no more interest for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, merging select and update in one query is good idea especially when it avoids much slower php loop. please consider following draft of the solution:

```
UPDATE table1 t1, table2 t1 SET t1.stock = t1.stock - t2.delta WHERE t1.id=t2.id and ...
```

You can also use fast temporary memory table (with semi-results from any SELECT) or sub-query instead of *table2*

Comment: Sql is like that for me : hard to find the right way, but so obvious when you can see the solution... btw you mispelled the table2 alias (t1 instead of t2). many thx